# Button click not working in my jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery

HI I have a jQuery dialog box which runs on page load and i want to achieve a functionality in which a jQuery dialog is closed only when terms and conditions checkbox is checked, but button click event not working.

```
$("<div title='E-Certificate'><h2 style = 'color:black'><b>Electronic Certificate of Origin</b></h2><p align = 'right' >،،، الاعضاء الكرام</p><p align = 'right'>تماشيا مع مبادرات الحكومة الذكية ومن ضمن جهود غرفة دبي لتسهيل الأعمال، يرجى العلم بأنه سيتم توثيق الفواتير </p><p align = 'right'>وبيانات التعبئة الخاصة بشهادة المنشأ تلقائيا من خلال النظام وذلك عوضا عن استخدام الملصق الحالي.</p><p align = 'right'>وسوف تكون الخدمة الزامية ابتداء من 18 نوفمبر 2017</p><p align = 'right'>،،، شاكرين لكم حسن تعاونكم</p><p align = 'left'>Dear Member,</p><p align = 'left'>In line with Dubai Smart Government initiative and as part of Dubai Chamber’s efforts to help members do business with ease, please be noted that invoices and packing list will be stamped automatically from the systems replacing the existing stickers.</p><p align = 'left'>Which will be mandatory from 18th Nov 2017.</p><p align='left'>Thanks for your cooperation.</p><p align='left'>،،،</p><br>For more details, please <a href = 'htmltemplates/DC%20Electronic%20COO%20User%20Guide.pdf'  target='_blank' style = 'color:blue'>click here</a><form action='#' onsubmit='if(document.getElementById('agree').checked) { return true; } else { alert('Please indicate that you have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy'); return false; }'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='check' id='agree' /> I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy\n<p></p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='CLose' style = 'background-color: #10304c;border: none;color: white;padding: 5px 5px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px; margin: 4px 2px;cursor: pointer;border-radius:2px; '/></form></div>").dialog();
```

here's the fiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/9z2ag/475/

Comment: here's the fiddle for above question:-http://jsfiddle.net/9z2ag/475/

Comment: There's a reason you were blocked from placing the link to the fiddle - the code should be placed ***within the question***. If jsFiddle goes down your question will be unanswerable. You should also show what efforts you made to solve the issue. The fiddle itself is only showing the dialog.

Comment: Where do you *try* to "close the dialog"?  Just adding the text "Close" to the button doesn't accomplish this, you have to write code to do it.

Comment: I used form tag and where i have placed my code , if box is checked then alert wont show , and if not then alert will pop up, but that too not working

Comment: Please use the `edit` button to add code to the question. Code in comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Add the button over the jueryui-creator like this:

```
$( "#dialog").dialog({
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    Ok: function() {

      if ("checkbox.checked") $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: but before that the click should work , you can see the fiddle not any of the js code that is written inside the form tag is functioning, neither if condition nor else.

Comment: you call "onclick = 'Akash();", but where is the function declaration?

Comment: that function includes a alert message just to check whether its working or not but its not calling that function too.

Comment: function includes a alert message just to check whether its calling function or not but its not. I even tried for onclick = "window.open()". but that too not working.

Comment: try to use to declare the onclick like the way in jquery-ui-doc:     $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });

Comment: In "#dialog" should i provide my html code.because I am using no seperate html, all my html is embedded here only.

Comment: can you please show this in fiddle, it will be a big help

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 300,
  width: 350,
  resizable: false,
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    'Ok' : function() {
      $("#dialog-form").dialog( "close" );  
    } 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("<div title='E-Certificate'><h2 style = 'color:black'><b>Electronic Certificate of Origin</b></h2><p align = 'right' >،،، الاعضاء الكرام</p><p align = 'right'>تماشيا مع مبادرات الحكومة الذكية ومن ضمن جهود غرفة دبي لتسهيل الأعمال، يرجى العلم بأنه سيتم توثيق الفواتير </p><p align = 'right'>وبيانات التعبئة الخاصة بشهادة المنشأ تلقائيا من خلال النظام وذلك عوضا عن استخدام الملصق الحالي.</p><p align = 'right'>وسوف تكون الخدمة الزامية ابتداء من 18 نوفمبر 2017</p><p align = 'right'>،،، شاكرين لكم حسن تعاونكم</p><p align = 'left'>Dear Member,</p><p align = 'left'>In line with Dubai Smart Government initiative and as part of Dubai Chamber’s efforts to help members do business with ease, please be noted that invoices and packing list will be stamped automatically from the systems replacing the existing stickers.</p><p align = 'left'>Which will be mandatory from 18th Nov 2017.</p><p align='left'>Thanks for your cooperation.</p><p align='left'>،،،</p><br>For more details, please <a href = 'htmltemplates/DC%20Electronic%20COO%20User%20Guide.pdf'  target='_blank' style = 'color:blue'>click here</a><br><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='check' id='agree' /> I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy\n<p></p><div id = 'openCandy'><input type='button' name='submit' value='Close'  style = 'background-color: #10304c;border: none;color: white;padding: 5px 5px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px; margin: 4px 2px;cursor: pointer;border-radius:2px; '/></div></form</div>").dialog();



 $('#openCandy').click(function() {
           if ( $('input[name="checkbox"]').is(':checked') ) {
            $(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close'); 
            }
            else {
            swal('Accept the terms and conditions.');
            //alert ("Please accept the terms and conditions !!")
            }
    });
```

This is my code and it worked for me